# How to pass table id generated within XSL via generate-id() function to the java script?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to call click function for each xsl value-of and display it via `alert()` function. `$("#{$CID} td").click(function()`
I am not able to pass the value that I generated in XSL (CID) to the java script function.

```
<xsl:template>
  <html>
    <head>
       <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#{$CID} td").click(function(){  
                         var value=$(this).data("value");
                           alert(value);              
                         });                    

        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
       <xsl:if test="count(/Files/notes/note) &gt;= 0">          
             <div class="section">
                <div colspan="4" class="sectionHeader">
                        <b>Sections</b>
                    </div>
<xsl:for-each select="/Files/notes/note">
<xsl:variable name="CID" select="generate-id()" />
<table id="{$CID}" width="100%" class="clsGridTableBase">
   <tr>                                
       <td data-value="{@AID}"> Note Id:
        <xsl:value-of select="@BID" />                              
    </td>                               
    </tr>
    </table>                        
   </xsl:for-each>
  </div>             
 </xsl:if>          
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call click function"? Where is the code that does this?

Comment: when I click on Note id:<value>, .click function gets called. similar to this one here - http://jsfiddle.net/uKaBH/   , only problem being I am not able to pass dynamic id from xsl to js.